# Get image size from PDImageXObject

Tags: java, image-processing, pdfbox

Is there a way to find out the size of the image (in bytes, in whatever compressed image format they're stored in) in PDImageXObject without extracting it into BufferedImage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `img.getCOSObject().getLength()`, this will give you the length of the COSStream on which the image is based. If the image has a mask, you'll have to do the same with it. Call `img.getMask()` to check whether there is one.